# to add events for a dynamically added button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have added a text area and buttons to a table dynamically

i want to add click event for this dynamically added buttons

How do i bind event to dynamically added element...

the script is shown here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#questType').change(function(){
        var id=$('#questType option:selected').val();
        var txt=$('#questType option:selected').text();
        if(id=='singleType'){
            document.getElementById('singleChoise').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('multipleChoise').style.display='none'
        }
        else if(id=='multipleType'){
            document.getElementById('multipleChoise').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('singleChoise').style.display='none'
        }
    });

     var cnt = 1;
     $(".addRadAnsw").click(function(){
         cnt++;
         $('#tbl1 tr').last().after('<tr><td><input type="radio" name="singAnsw" value="answ'+cnt+'"/></td><td><textarea rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="this is answer'+cnt+'"></textarea><button class="addRadAnsw">ADD</button><button class="remRadAnsw">DELETE</button><br/><hr width="500px;"/></td></tr>'); 
         return false;
     });

    $(".remRadAnsw").click(function(){
     cnt--;
     $('#tbl1 tr:last-child').remove();
     return false;
    });

    var cnt1 = 1;
     $(".addChkAnsw").click(function(){
         cnt1++;
         $('#tbl2 tr').last().after('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="multAnsw" value="answ'+cnt1+'"/></td><td><textarea rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="this is answer'+cnt1+'"></textarea><button class="addChkAnsw">ADD</button><button class="remChkAnsw">DELETE</button><br/><hr width="500px;"/></td></tr>'); 
         return false;
     });

    $(".remChkAnsw").click(function(){
     cnt1--;
     $('#tbl2 tr:last-child').remove();
     return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: You need to look at delegated events in the jQuery api http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.addChkAnsw', function(e) {
   //Dynamic added button clicked
   //Remove parent tablerow
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: but i need to delete the selected row on button delete click??? how is it possible?

Comment: inside the function:
`$(this).parent().parent().remove();`
This will remove the parent tablerow of the button that is clicked

Comment: how do i iterate through this table and get values from each row that has checkbox and textfields and send a json object of this

Answer (score 3):

jQuery On
https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("selector").on("click",function(){
  // action
});
```

Comment: or the onclick event in your button. `<button onClick="function()">`

Comment: i have added  $(".addChkAnsw").on("click",(function(){    ......});     but its not working...

Comment: im using jquery version 10 and used live ,,,, still have the problem

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, this is just copying an pasting from jQuery documentation.  It also makes no mention of delegating events which is what is needed in this situation as the elements are added dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `addRadAnsw` and `remRadAnsw` buttons are added dynamically, this is how you would listen to them.

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.remRadAnsw', function(e) {
    button = $(this);
    button.text("I've been clicked!");
});

$('body').on('click', 'button.addRadAnsw', function(e) {
    button = $(this);
    button.text("I've been clicked!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'button.remRadAnsw', function(e) {
        $(this).text("Clicked!");
    });
});
```